# Count wrong answer

Tags: java

I am trying to create java application.
It ask questions and have 4 choices for each question.

I want to count total right and wrong answers selected by the user.

I am using function like this-

```
public void checkAnswer(String choice)
{
    int correctcount=0;
    int wrongcount=0;
    if(counter==1) {
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
            correctAnswerDisplay();
            correctcount = correct count + 1;
        } else {
            wrongAnswerDisplay();
            wrongcount = wroungcount + 1;
        }
    }
    else if(counter==2) {
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
            correctAnswerDisplay();
        } else {
            wrongAnswerDisplay();
        }
}
```

Basically I hardcoded answers for each question.
For e.g- For this question, correct answer is "A". so I said if its "a" call the correct answer function else wrong answer in question#1. Counter variable is to display next questions

How can i calculate total right and wrong answer of all question. I have allowed users to select another option if they answer wrong, so they don't get to next question until they select right answer. But every time when they select wrong answer counter will add more numbers it should allow only 1 addition and stop there.

Also, lets says i selected wrong answer, I won't get next question until i hit continue button, and continue button appears only when i select correct answer. So if i select wrong answer 2 times, counter will be 2. It should work as i select wrong answer even three times, total wrong answer count should be just 1. and person will always select correct answer once for each question because continue button doesn't appear until then. So it should not increase correct counter if wrong answer was selected first.

Sorry I am a new programmer. Please help.

Comment: Every time you call `checkAnswer()`, the values of `correctcount` and `wrongcount` will be set to 0

Comment: Assuming the intention is to see if each question had atleast one wrong answer, you should use flags rather than counters. And in case you have more questions, a switch case would be better than an if...else... in terms of performance. Instead of checking which case is satisfied, it only decides which case has to be executed.

Comment: Make sure to post code that compiles. This code does not

Answer (score 0):

```
package org.test.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestMain {

    public int correctcount = 0;
    public int wrongcount = 0;
    public int counter = 1; // lets assume you have counter as 1 to start with

    public void checkAnswer(String choice) {
        if (counter == 1) {
            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
                correctAnswerDisplay();
                correctcount = correctcount + 1;
            } else {
                wrongAnswerDisplay();
                wrongcount = wrongcount + 1;
            }
        } else if (counter == 2) {
            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
                correctAnswerDisplay();
                correctcount = correctcount + 1;
            } else {
                wrongAnswerDisplay();
                wrongcount = wrongcount + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void wrongAnswerDisplay() {
        System.out.println("Wrong");

    }

    private void correctAnswerDisplay() {
        System.out.println("Correct");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestMain testM = new TestMain();
        Scanner scanNext = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i < 2;i++) {
            System.out.print("Question#"+(i+1)+": ");
            String ans = scanNext.nextLine();
            testM.checkAnswer(ans);
            testM.counter++;
        }

        System.out.println("Number of Correct Answer:" + testM.correctcount);
        System.out.println("Number of Wrong Answer:" + testM.wrongcount);

    }
}
```

Make your `correctcount` and `wrongcount` as instance variable. because every time you call the method checkAnswer(), 0 will be assigned in the 2 variables you created in your method.

I tried to simulate your logic. so try this. The numbers of question and the answers are hardcoded. so change it in your logic to be dynamic. I write this code to understand how the incrementation works.

Comment: Sorry I am still confused. So, if I change code like this-

Comment: show us all what you got. edit your post to help others too.

Comment: This is still counting correct answer, if i select wrong answer first.

Comment: hei. if you input "a" first. that would be correct. it's in your code. if you put other string over "a", it will give you wrong. and after that the counter will be move to 2 which is the "d" is the correct answer. check it.

Comment: If my answer helps you. please check to help others too.

Answer (score 0):

It is a really good thing that you have started using communities like Stackoverflow.

Form the question it is clear that there is a continue button which will be enabled only if you select the correct answer. (Then there is no point in counting correct answers since with such a button, at the end you will have all the questions answered correctly. Anyway if you really want this logic to work try the following.)

Let's create a method `incrementWrongCount()` to increment the variable wrongcount.

```
public class AnswerTester{
    int correctcount = 0;
    int wrongcount = 0;

    /*Following variable indicates whether you have selected any wrong answers before
    selecting the right answer. Obviously its default value is false since you 
    have selected no wrong answers (in fact no answers) when you first
    you first answers a question*/
    boolean wronganswerselected = false; 

    public void checkAnswer(int counter, String choice){
       if(counter==1) {
            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
                correctAnswerDisplay();
                correctcount = correctcount + 1;
                incrementWrongCount();
                wronganswerselected = false;//For the next question
                enableContinueButton();
            } else {
                wrongAnswerDisplay();
                wronganswerselected = true;//just indicate that you have selected a wrong answer. We will increment wrong count in incrementWrongCount()
                disableContinueButton();
            }
        } else if(counter==2) {
            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
                correctAnswerDisplay();
                correctcount = correctcount + 1;
                incrementWrongCount();
                wronganswerselected = false;
                enableContinueButton();
            } else {
                wrongAnswerDisplay();
                wronganswerselected = true;
                disableContinueButton();
            }
        }
    }

    private void incrementWrongCount(){
        if(wronganswerselected){//Should increment wrongcount only if the user have selected atleast one wrong answer.
            wrongcount = wrongcount + 1;
        }
    }

    private void correctAnswerDisplay(){
        System.out.println("Correct..");
    }

    private void wrongAnswerDisplay(){
        System.out.println("Wrong..");
    }

    public int getCorrectCount(){
        return correctcount;
    }

    public int getWrongCount(){
        return wrongcount;
    }

}
```

Its a good practice to use switch instead of if...else if to match a variable against multiple values.

Comment: THAT Works.....you are a genius...Thank you very much. God bless you :)